# How to exchange data between nodes?

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to send data from one node to another. For example: One node is publishing data to the topic `/mobile_base/commands/velocity` and other one is subscribed to `/mobile_base/events/bumper`. Both the subscriber & publisher are working fine.

What I want to do is to make the robot move backward once the bumpers are pressed. I do not know how to send the event of bumper pressed to the other node.

The solution I thought was of using pipes or sockets or shared memory to exchange data between two nodes.

Is this the right approach? Or does ROS has a builtin method for that?

Thanks in Advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/111166/how-to-exchange-data-between-nodes?/) by [Safeer](https://answers.ros.org/users/9456/safeer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2013-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, you should create an intermediate node wich subscribe to `/mobile_base/events/bumper` and publish on `/mobile_base/commands/velocity`. In this node, create your reactive behaviour.

No need of pipes and sockets, the publisher/subscriber mechanism is develloped to allows the communications.

---

Originally posted by [David Galdeano](https://answers.ros.org/users/9481/david-galdeano/) with karma: 357 on 2013-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can just subscribe /mobile_base/events/bumper in the node that publishes velocity directly.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-12-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Safeer](https://answers.ros.org/users/9456/safeer/) on 2013-12-16**:
I have tried this. The problem I faced was that when bumper was pressed, the robot stopped moving i.e. once the subscriber receive the *bumper pressed(signal)* it stopped publishing to *Velocity* topic.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-17**:
If it stopped publishing than that is a bug in your code. However, are you sure that is the cause? The earlier Kobuki firmware did stop the robot on bumper press internally as a "feature".

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2013-12-17**:
I agree, that must be a problem with your code. Just make that the callback that answers to /mobile_base/events/bumper raises a "bumperPressed" flag and check that flag in your main thread to move forward or backward.